# callback function is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, callback

I have used callback function for checking whether the email is active or not:
My controller is not accessing the callback function.

my controller code:

```
     function index() { 
    //Session redirection
    header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('created_user_id');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('created_user_type');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('edit_user_type');
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('terms', 'Terms', 'trim|required');
        if($this->input->post('email'))
        { 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'callback_email_check');
        } echo "out"; die;
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error_user" style="color:red">', '</div>');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){ 
                if($this->input->post('Join')!="") {
                $this->session->set_userdata('join_email', $this->input->post('email'));
                    redirect(base_url().'caregivers/my-account');
                }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('site/landing-page');  

}
```

My callback function code:

```
    public function email_check(){   
    $get_status = $this->web_user_model->get_status($this->input->post('email'));   
    if($get_status['is_active']=='1')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check','Email ID already Exits');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

I dont know where i have done the mistake.
Can anyone help me???
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set twice your validation rule :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
....
if($this->input->post('email'))
{ 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'callback_email_check');
 }
```

this is useless because you already set your email field to required so the if is already checked by the validation rule.

Try :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
```

Also your callback function should expect one parameter

```
public function email_check($email)
{
     $get_status = $this->web_user_model->get_status($email);
     ...
```